# RewriteRule in .htacces not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file I have several 301 redirects.

The following line works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^sub1/ https://example.com/sub1  [L,R=301]
```

However, if there is another / in de url, the page will not be redirected properly.

```
RewriteRule ^sub1/sub2/ https://www.example.com/sub  [L,R=301]
```

This will end up at example.com/sub1/sub2/ although it loads the page of example.com/sub1 as it does nothing with the /sub2.

How can I force the correct url rewriting?

**EDIT**
I also have some lines to remove .php in the .htaccess that might be causing this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you try to remove the slash right after the 'sub2'? So it become RewriteRule ^sub1/sub2 https://www.example.com/sub  [L,R=301] .

Comment: Results in the same. I've updated the post. Forgot to mention about the .php removal.

Comment: Sounds like you placed the second rewriting rule after the first one. The first one is executed first, it matches also the URL of the second request.